# Problem using '-' inside an optional argument when using Python Argparse

Tags: python, argparse, optional-arguments

I am parsing an argument input:

```
python parser_test.py --p "-999,-99;-9"
```

I get this error:

```
parser_test.py: error: argument --p: expected one argument
```

Is there a particular reason why including '-' in the optional argument

```
"-999,-99;-9"
```

throws the error even while within double quotes?  I need to be able to include the '-' sign.

Here is the code:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Input command line arguments for the averaging program')
    parser.add_argument('--p', help='input the missing data filler as an integer')
    args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the code by which you set up `argparse`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I just added the relevant code snippet.  It is pretty straightforward.  I get no error if I remove the '-' sign from the optional argument --p.

Comment: You haven’t specified that the —p option takes a value, so argparse is consuming the —p and then looking at the next thing on the command line as the start of another option.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing

Comment: @barny that's not correct. The default `action` is `'store'` and OP didn't specify anything else. Your statement does not align with the error which clearly states `argument --p: expected one argument`

Comment: The double quotes are for the benefit of the shell, not Python. The problem is that `argparse` identifies potential options before it considers whether an option takes an argument, and `-999,-99;-9` looks like an option.

Comment: Use `--p="-999,-99;-9"`, because that's a *single* word, as opposed to the pair of words `--p` and `-999,-99;-9`.

Comment: @chepner how does your previous comment connects to the fact that `--p -999` does work fine? It seems like the problem is not with the **first** `-`

Comment: @Tomerikoo `argparse` uses a heuristic to special-case negative numbers.

Comment: @chepner I see. So `-999,-99;-9` breaks because of all the symbols in the middle and considered as another option?

Comment: Correct. From Pranav's link: "The parse_args() method is cautious here: positional arguments may only begin with - if they look like negative numbers and there are no options in the parser that look like negative numbers:"

Comment: @chepner one last thing: In the docs they talk about positional arguments or options. Here we deal with an option's argument. I guess that for that matter it is considered the same as a positional argument?

Comment: I think it's two different uses of the term "positional argument". The Python process just receives a list of words for arguments. `argparse` takes that list and classifies each as a potential option or not before looking at the option definitions. So when it is deciding if `-999,-99;-9` is an option or not, it hasn't yet looked at the definition of `-p` to see that it takes an argument.

Comment: @chepner that makes sense... Thanks alot for the clarfication!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why are positional arguments being discussed here?  I can see how adding a '-' sign in front of a positional argument might complicate things, but I am using an optional argument enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @bernski The only purpose the quotes serve is to prevent the shell from treating `;` as a command terminator. You would get the exact same behavior with `-p -999,-99";"-9`, as Python will get the same arguments, `-p` and `-999,-99;-9`, either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes do nothing to alter how `argparse` treats the `-`; the only purpose they serve is to prevent the shell from treating the `;` as a command terminator.

`argparse` looks at *all* the arguments first and identifies which ones *might* be options, regardless of what options are actually defined, by checking which ones start with `-`. It makes an exception for things that could be negative numbers (like `-999`), but only if there are no defined options that look like numbers.

The solution is to prevent `argparse` from seeing `-999,-99;-9` as a separate argument. Make it *part* of the argument that contains the `-p` using the `--name=value` form.

```
python parser_test.py --p="-999,-99;-9"
```

You can also use `"--p=-999,-99;-9"` or `--p=-999,-99\;-9`, among many other possibilities for writing an argument that will cause the shell to parse your command line as two separate commands, `python parser_test.py --p-999,-99` and `-9`.